# Issue with installing External Libraries in Streamsets Data Collector

Tags: streamsets

I have a ridiculous issue with installing External Libraries, I've done all steps from Streamsets's document but after restarting Streamsets I got this error : Expected exactly 1 stage lib jar but found 2 with name streamsets-datacollector-jdbc-lib. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue.
I added mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar to the streamsets-datacollector-jdbc-lib folder.